# Skip human task in jbpm 6.3 via script (java)

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

is there anyone know how to skip a human task via script?

I have been trying to find it in jBPM forum, but there is no answer.

thanks

Comment: Isn't there a "Skippable" option on the jBPM eclipse modeler for the human task?

Answer (score 0):

You may not need a script to skip a human task. You could just create a data-based exclusive (XOR) gateway to check whether you need to perform the task or not. Consider the design as below, should give you some idea on how to implement your scenario.

[image]